# Correlation analysis on sales data (e.g., Click through rate of different pages x Conversion rate of different pages)

Tags: correlation, business-intelligence

I am looking into e-commerce page sales data, and I am wondering if pearson correlation analysis can be done on data set like below.

Each of the variable (e.g., conversion rate, CTR) is based on 10000+ data points. There are 10 pages to analyze. I am curious to see things like if conversion rate is related to Click through rate, if # of items on each of the page is tied to conversion rate or unit per transaction etc.

| Page | Conversion Rate % | Click Through Rate % | Unit per transaction | # of items on page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Page A | 2.19 | 8.10 | 3.5 | 9 |
| Page B | .11 | .57 | 2.6 | 5 |
| Page C | 4.77 | 11.3 | 4.2 | 6 |
| Page D | 3.2 | 9.05 | 5.1 | 7 |
| Page X | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Welcome user392306! From the data that you show here (thumbs up!) it looks as if there is a strong correlation between conversion rate and click through rate. Is this all you want to show in your analysis, or do you want to relate the ratio for these rates to other variables (e.g. Page)?